# Matching html tags with conditional regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use conditional regex to match either `<label>` or `<label title="test"...>`

My reqular expression is the following:

```
<label(\s?)(?(1)\w+)>
```

From my understanding that means if the optional space is matched it should follow with a series of characters. There is no else condition thus it should just follow with `>`

In python CLI, I do the following

```
re.search('<label(\s?)(?(1)\w+)>','<label>') # fails, no match
re.search('<label(\s?)(?(1)\w+)>','<label title=>') # matches
```

So I am able to match a label with attributes but how do I go about matching a plain label as well? Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `[^>]*` to match everything until you hit `>`.

```
re.search('<label([^>]*)>','<label title=>') # matches
re.search('<label([^>]*)>','<label>') # matches
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use the OR operator (`|`):

```
re.search('<label(\s?)(?(1)\w+)>|<label>','<label>') # matches
re.search('<label(\s?)(?(1)\w+)>|<label>','<label title=>') # matches
```

Comment: works but I was hoping for a more elegant solution, eventhough I couldn't think of this answer at the time :)